# Facebook: Add an external profile into facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I want to build a facebook application and don't know how to plan it. A facebook user should find that application and click a button there, something like: "Add this Application to your facebook page". After that (or when the user first opens the app tab) the user will be asked to log into an external website. When the credentials are okay and the user is the owner of that facebook page/tab then this external web application will display an external profile page of that facebook user (the owner of the facebook profile the app has been put in). After that the user doesn't have to log in anymore and every user that visits that tab will see the external profile of that facebook page.

...To make it more clear an example:

User Foo has got an account at example.com and a public visitable profile there example.com/profiles/Foo. User A has also got a facebook page. Now example.com tells its users that they developed a facebook app to integrate their example.com-profiles into their facebook profiles. So the user A opens that apps page, clicks a button, logs into example.com and now has a new tab at her facebook page that contains example.com/profiles/Foo. If user B visits the facebook page of user A, he will find the example.com-profile of user A (not B) in the application tab.

What I would need is the following information:

- How can I make an application available for the facebook users?

**Update:** found this tutorial: http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-removing-app-profile-pages-on-feb-1-2012/

- Is it possible to make something like an installation process of an app? Otherwise if user A clicks the button to integrate the app into her page and user B opens the tab before user A could open it and log into the example.com, then user B could log in and his example.com profile would appear in the facebook page of user A. Or how can I solve this problem.
- Next problem is that--I think--the URL of the application will be the same for all users, that integrate this app into their profile. So I would need to be able to detect the facebook page of a app request.

**Update:** I will be able to read the page ID from the [`signed request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). Problem seams to be that the page administrator must know his/her page ID, but I think it will be possible to retrieve it through the graph API (if it is not part of the URL).

Comment: Apps can not be “installed” on user profile pages, only on Facebook pages (a.k.a. “fan pages”).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I've heard that.